# Using msforeachtable for getting list of tables of a specific database

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

In this stored procedure I want to get list of all the tables of a specific database when I give the database name as input.

For example when I call `sp_list(master)` it shows me the tables of the `master` database.

How can do this using `sp_msforeachtable`?

I found this code

```
sp_msforeachtable ' select ''?'' as ''Table'', count(*) as ''Rows'' from ? '
```

but cannot give database name in it as input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this webpage](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/324992/Getting-List-Of-Tables-Of-An-Specific-Database-Usi):

> ```
> declare @query as nvarchar(max)
> declare @dbname as nvarchar(max)
> SET @query=''
> SET @dbname ='TST'
> SET @query =@query + @dbname + '..sp_msforeachtable '' select ''''?'''' as ''''Table'''', count(*) as ''''Rows'''' from ? '''
>
> EXEC sp_executesql @query
> ```